# Spyne Soap server with WSDL-file

Tags: python, soap, wsdl, spyne

I'm trying to port a Soap server from an old PHP project to Python. Django to be exact. 
In PHP you use

```
$server = new SOAPServer("xyz.wsdl", ....
```

As far as I know this

```
app = Application([HelloWorldService], 'spyne.examples.hello.http',
    in_protocol=Soap11(validator='lxml'),
    out_protocol=Soap11(),
)
```

is the only way to start a Soap server with Spyne, so does Spyne have the ability to use a WSDL-file to create a Soap server?

Comment: Spyne does not have a wsdl parser as of 2.13. Patches are welcome.

Comment: A SOAP framework without the ability to read WSDL files? You must be joking.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think so! As it was my question one day, and couldn't find any solution to create a soap server from WSDL file, finally I've started to write codes to generate WDSL file and create a Soap Server. 
Spyne documentation was very helpful for me, I extremely recommend it.